# TR01_APP caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TR01_APP: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, limits, cpulimit

We have trigger named TR01_APP which fires when we update the record. Here we update one record from salesforce UI to update a new User by replacing old User and found the below error Message.
"Error:Apex trigger TR01_APP caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: TR01_APP: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded"
We have not faced this issue since lat week and there was not modification or code changes have happened to this trigger.
I did checked debug and found the same error for a different trigger handler class on Opportunity. And found error message like below:
Class HLP01_OPP System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded line 315

Please find the class details and trigger details:

TR01_APP:

```
trigger TR01_APP on Approver__c (After Update) {

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate ){
    HLP01_APP.UpdateAPP(Trigger.new);
}
```

}

HLP01_APP handler:

```
public class HLP01_APP {

public static void UpdateAPP(List<Approver__c> lstAppro){
    // Country Affected        
    Set<String> setCountryOpp = new Set<String>();  
    Set<String> setCountryURM = new Set<String>();
    Approver__c thisapprover = new Approver__c();
    
    For(Approver__c oneAppro : lstAppro){
        if(oneAppro.APP_Type_Approval__c == 'Opportunity'){
            setCountryOpp.add(oneAppro.APP_CCR_Country__c);
        } else if(oneAppro.APP_Type_Approval__c == 'Case Users'){
            setCountryURM.add(oneAppro.APP_CCR_Country__c);
        }
        thisapprover = oneAppro;
    } 
    
    // Retrieve Opportunity
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp =[Select id, owner.ccr_country__c, name,
                               OPP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c, OPP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c, OPP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c, OPP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c,
                               OPP_Approver_Level1_Sale__c, OPP_Approver_Level2_Sale__c, OPP_Approver_Level3_Sale__c, OPP_Approver_Level4_Sale__c
                               from opportunity
                               where owner.ccr_country__c in: setCountryOpp
                               and stagename not in ('6. Won - Cash','Closed Lost','Closed / Not realized')];
    
    // Retrieve Case
    List<Case> lstCase =[Select id, CASE_URM_CCR_Country__c, CASE_URM_Local_Area__c,
                         Case_URM_Approver_L1_Supervisor__c, Case_URM_Approver_L2_Managing_Director__c, Case_URM_Approver_L3_RGM__c, Case_URM_Approver_L4_KA_Director__c
                         from Case
                         where CASE_URM_CCR_Country__c  in: setCountryURM
                         and Status = 'new'];
           
    
    if(lstOpp.size()>0){
        system.debug('OPP TO UPDATE');
        UpdateApproverOpp(lstOpp, thisapprover); 
    }
    if(lstCase.size()>0){
        system.debug('CASE TO UPDATE');
        UpdateApproverCase(lstCase);
    }
}        

//Update All the Opportunity linked with an Updated Approved.
public static void UpdateApproverOpp(List<Opportunity> listOpp, Approver__c thisapprover){                
    system.debug('-- Update Approver Opp--');        
    // All Approver Record in SF
    List<Approver__c> listAppro =[SELECT Id, APP_CCR_Local_Area__c, APP_CCR_Country__c, APP_Type_Approval__c ,
                                  APP_Approver_L1_Sales_Director__c, APP_Approver_L2_Managing_Director__c, APP_Approver_L3_Regional_General_Manager__c, APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_General_Manager__c,
                                  APP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c, APP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c, APP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c, APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c                                      
                                  FROM Approver__c where APP_Type_Approval__c = 'Opportunity'];
    
    // Id Opportunity Owner
    Set<Id> setIdUser =  new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Opportunity oneOppo : listOpp){
        setIdUser.add(oneOppo.OwnerId);
    } 
    
    // Map Users related to the Opportunity
    Map<Id,User> mapUser = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id, CCR_Country__c, CCR_Local_Area__c FROM User where id in: setIdUser]);
    
    List<Opportunity> listToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    
    // Fill/Empty fields if needed
    For(Opportunity oneOPP : listOpp){
        // Clean all the approvers fieldS
        // Approver Sales
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level1_Sale__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level2_Sale__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level3_Sale__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level4_Sale__c = null;
        // Approver Finance
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c = null;
        oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c  = null;
        
        For(Approver__c oneAppro : listAppro){ 
            // Case Germany - Check local Area
            If(mapUser.get(oneOPP.ownerid).CCR_Country__c == 'CCR Germany'){
                if(mapUser.get(oneOPP.ownerid).CCR_Local_Area__c == oneAppro.APP_CCR_Local_Area__c
                   && mapUser.get(oneOPP.ownerid).CCR_Country__c == oneAppro.APP_CCR_Country__c){
                       system.debug('Match - Germany');                       
                       // Approvers Sales                       
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level1_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L1_Sales_Director__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level2_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L2_Managing_Director__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level3_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L3_Regional_General_Manager__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level4_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_General_Manager__c;
                       
                       // Approvers Finance
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c;
                       oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c  = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c;                                                                                           
                   }
            } else {
                // Case Not Germany - no local area)
                if(mapUser.get(oneOPP.ownerid).CCR_Country__c == oneAppro.APP_CCR_Country__c){
                    system.debug('Match - Other Country');                       
                    // Approvers Sales                       
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level1_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L1_Sales_Director__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level2_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L2_Managing_Director__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level3_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L3_Regional_General_Manager__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_Level4_Sale__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_General_Manager__c;
                    
                    // Approvers Finance
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L1_Local_Controller__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L2_Local_CFO__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L3_Regional_CFO__c;
                    oneOPP.OPP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c  = oneAppro.APP_Approver_L4_EMEA_CFO__c;
                }
            }                
        }  
        System.debug(oneOPP);
        listToUpdate.add(oneOPP);
    }        
    
    if(listToUpdate.size() > 0){            
        //update listToUpdate;
        
        string error ='';
        // Test pour améliorer le code
        Try{                                          
            List<Database.SaveResult> sr = Database.update(listToUpdate,false); 
            
            for (Integer i = 0; i < sr.size(); i++) {
            system.debug(i);
                if (sr[i].isSuccess()) {
                    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                    system.debug(sr[i].getid());
                    system.debug(listToUpdate[i].id);
                    system.debug(' Update Complete ');
                }
                else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Database.Error err : sr[i].getErrors()) { 
                        system.debug(sr[i]);
                        error += '=> '+err.getMessage()+' '+ listToUpdate[i].id+' '+listToUpdate[i].name+' -- ';                       
                    }
                    system.debug(' Error ');                        
                } 
            }
        } catch(exception e){   
            system.debug('List Error:' +error);                
        }
        
        if(error != ''){
            thisapprover.addError(error);
        }            
    }
}
```

}

Opportunity Trigger Handler class:

```
public class HLP01_OPP {

// methode for replace PB10

public static void CreateApprovalHistory(List<Opportunity> listOpp ){
    // List Id for instance        
    Set<id> setId= new Set<id>();
    for(Opportunity oneOppId : listOpp){            
        if(oneOppId.OPP_CT_Trigger_AHT__c == true){
            setid.add(oneOppId.id);
        }
    }        
    
    if(setid.size() > 0){  
        // Map All Opp that must trigger Approval history creation.
        Map<Id,Opportunity> MapOpp = new Map<id, Opportunity>([Select id, OPP_CT_Trigger_AHT__c from Opportunity where id in: setid]);
        
        // Map Process node for name
        Map<id,ProcessNode> mpProName = new Map<id,ProcessNode>([SELECT Id, Name FROM ProcessNode]);
        system.debug(mpProName);
        
        // List Process instance completed today
        List<ProcessInstance> listPI =[SELECT TargetObjectId, (SELECT Id, TargetObjectId, StepStatus, ProcessNodeid, OriginalActorId, ActorId , createddate
                                                               FROM StepsAndWorkitems where StepStatus in ('Approved','Rejected') order by createddate ASC)
                                       FROM ProcessInstance where completeddate= today];
        
        System.debug('List PI '+listPI);
        
        Map<id,List<ProcessInstancehistory>> mapStep = new Map<id,List<ProcessInstancehistory>>();
        for(ProcessInstance onePI : listPI){
            mapStep.put(onePI.TargetObjectId, onePI.StepsAndWorkitems);
        }
        
        system.debug('Map Step '+mapStep);   
        
        List<Approval_History_Tracking__c> lstAHT = new List<Approval_History_Tracking__c>();
        
        // For each Opportunity in Process
        // Create AHT record after complete Approval
        For(Opportunity oneOpp : listOpp){
            // List Process instance history for this Opp
            List<ProcessInstancehistory> lstPIH = new List<ProcessInstancehistory>();
            lstPIH = mapStep.get(oneOpp.id);
            
            system.debug('PIH for One Opp '+lstPIH);
            
            if(lstPIH.size() > 0){
                For(ProcessInstanceHistory onePIH : lstPIH){
                    // create AHT
                    Approval_History_Tracking__c oneAHT = new Approval_History_Tracking__c();
                    
                    // Currency
                    oneAHT.CurrencyIsoCode =  oneOpp.CurrencyIsoCode;                   
                    // Opportunity fields
                    oneAHT.AHT_Opportunity__c=oneOpp.id;
                    // Amount
                    oneAHT.AHT_Amount__c=oneOpp.Amount;
                    // SalesMargin
                    oneAHT.AHT_Sales_Margin__c=oneOpp.Sales_Margin__c;
                    // Order Value
                    oneAHT.AHT_Order_Value__c=oneOpp.OPP_Order_Value_and_currency__c;
                    // Order GM%
                    oneAHT.AHT_Order_GM__c=oneOpp.OPP_GM__c;
                    // LatestOrderValue
                    oneAHT.AHT_Latest_Order_Value__c=oneOpp.OPP_Latest_Order_value_and_currency__c;
                    // LatestOrderGM%
                    oneAHT.AHT_Latest_Order_GM__c=oneOpp.OPP_Latest_Order_GM__c;                                 
                    
                    // Approver
                    oneAHT.AHT_Approver__c = onePIH.ActorId;                  
                    
                    // Type Approval                        
                    If(onePIH.ProcessNodeId == null){
                        oneAHT.AHT_Type_Approval__c = autoApprovalType(oneOpp.OPP_Level_of_Approval__c);
                    } else {
                        oneAHT.AHT_Type_Approval__c = approvalType(mpProName.get(onePIH.ProcessNodeId).name);
                    }        
                    // Level Approval  
                    If(onePIH.ProcessNodeId == null){
                        oneAHT.AHT_Level_of_Approval__c = 'Auto-Approval';
                    } else {
                        oneAHT.AHT_Level_of_Approval__c = approvalLevel(mpProName.get(onePIH.ProcessNodeId).name);
                    } 
                    
                    // Status
                    oneAHT.AHT_Status__c = onePIH.StepStatus;  
                    // Date of Approval
                    oneAHT.AHT_Date_of_Approval__c = onePIH.createddate;                        
                    
                    lstAHT.add(oneAHT);
                }
                // uncheck OPP for cancel other creation
                MapOpp.get(oneOpp.id).OPP_CT_Trigger_AHT__c = false;
            }
        }
        System.debug(lstAHT);
        insert lstAHT;
        update MapOpp.values();
    }
}

public static String approvalType(String nodeType){
    String apptype = '';
    
    if(nodeType.contains('Opp')){
        apptype = 'Opportunity';
    } else if(nodeType.contains('Order Upd')){
        apptype = 'Order Update';
    } else if(nodeType.contains('Order')){
        apptype = 'Order';
    }
    return apptype;
}

public static String approvalLevel(String nodeLevel){
    String appLevel = '';
    
    if(nodeLevel.contains('.1')){
        appLevel = 'Level 1';
    } else if(nodeLevel.contains('.2')){
        appLevel = 'Level 2';
    } else if(nodeLevel.contains('.3')){
        appLevel = 'Level 3';
    } else if(nodeLevel.contains('.4')){
        appLevel = 'Level 4';
    }
    return appLevel;
} 

public static String autoApprovalType(decimal OPPlevel){
    String apptype = '';
    
    if(OPPlevel == 0){
        apptype = 'Opportunity';
    } else if(OPPlevel == 1){
        apptype = 'Order';
    } else if(OPPlevel == 2){
        apptype = 'Order Update';
    }
    return apptype;
}
```

}

Opp trigger:

```
trigger TR01_OPP on Opportunity (Before insert, After Update, after Insert) {
   

   if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert ){ 
       for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.new){
           if(opp.isclone() && (opp.StageName=='4. Finalizing' || opp.StageName=='5. Won - Execution' || opp.StageName== '6. Won - Cash') ){
               opp.addError('cannot create opportunity above Stage 3.Offer');
           }
           
       }
    HLP01_OPP.CleanOpportunityListBeforeInsert(trigger.new);        
}
if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert ){        
    HLP01_OPP.UpdateApproLevel(trigger.new, trigger.oldmap, false);        
}

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
    // Create Approval History Tracking Object
    HLP01_OPP.CreateApprovalHistory(trigger.new);        
    
    HLP01_OPP.CleanOpportunityListAfterUpdate(trigger.new, trigger.oldmap);
    HLP01_OPP.UpdateApproLevel(trigger.new, trigger.oldmap, true);        
}
```

}

Please help on how to identify and fix the cpu limit exceed error.
Thanks.

Comment: A debug log will definitely help. Using developer console and debug log you can find which operation is taking time. I see you have nested loops but that does seems to be a problem.  It can be that the method UpdateOpportunityApprover is called multiple times. Check how many times this debug is printed.`-- Update Approver Opp--`. It can be that the code in the post is fine and some other code is causing the issue.

Comment: @manjit5190 I tried looking for -- Update Approver Opp-- in my debug logs but I could not see even one.Just lot of Logs when I downloaded it it comes 19MB size

Comment: @SamuelRobert Are you able to share the debug log? Assuming it doesn't have any sensitive data in in. It should indicate why the CPU limit is being hit. Or at least provide indications of where the CPU limit is being consumed.

Comment: @DanielBallinger  When I was analysing the code I have found the issue in the abouve class HLP01_APP look for //Retreive Opportunity that query around 3148 records which is the issue since, Apex trigger process only 1000 records . hence I added limit 1000 to the query it worked for me so Now I have planned to rewrite the code as batch class.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you are making a trigger on Opportunity you wouldn't then be running another SOQL query on Opportunity to find the same records. That may or may not be the case here.